# How Google Maps pricing works?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-cloud-platform, expo

I'm working on an React Native App, using Expo. In the App I have a Map.

Expo Map is: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view
As you can see, Expo Map is basically this: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps.

I have 2 Google Maps ApiKeys, as you can see in this chart (taken from Google Cloud):
[image: Google Map usage]

The Blue line, is the React Native ApiKey usage. Only 1 usage!

The Orange line, is the Web ApiKey usage. A lot of usages!

The Orange usage makes all the sense, because I refreshed the page like 70 times, in that day, so, I have 70 usages in web.

Now, my question:
Why is the Blue line (ApiKey for React Native App) usage pointing only 1 usage? I loaded the Map on my phone close to 1 million times!
Why Google Maps for Web considers 1 usage everytime you refresh the page, and why Google Maps for Mobile considers the usage only 1 time (per device, maybe?)
Is it OK? Is Google considering "one usage" 1 time per device?

Comment: I believe this is a question for Google Maps Platform support team. You can ask them directly via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support.